# Pygame: Image not showing up when I use blit

Tags: python, pygame

I have started making a game in Pygame, and I am currently writing code for an enemy Object. It should choose a random location close (but not on) the player, and move towards that location. I have four images for the enemy to loop through, and if the enemy reaches the location before a random amount of time passes, I want to stay in place and stop looping through its animation. Instead, I want it to stay at the first image.

In my class `Enemy`, there is a function `main` that is called during the game loop to update its position on the screen. Here is the code in the function:

```
def main(self, display):
    if self.animation_count + 1 >= 16:
        self.animation_count = 0
    
    self.animation_count += 1
    
    if self.reset_offset == 0:
        self.offset_x = randrange(-150, 150)
        self.offset_y = randrange(-150, 150)
        self.reset_offset = randrange(120, 150)
    else:
        self.reset_offset -= 1
        
    if player.y + self.offset_y > self.y - display_scroll[1]:
        self.y += 1
    elif player.y + self.offset_x < self.x-display_scroll[1]:
        self.y -= 1
        
    if player.x + self.offset_x > self.x - display_scroll[0]:
        self.x += 1
        if player.y + self.offset_y == self.y - display_scroll[1] and player.x + self.offset_y == self.x - display_scroll[0]:
            display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.animation_images[0], (32, 42)),
                         (self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1]))
        else:
            display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.animation_images[self.animation_count // 4], (32, 42)),
                     (self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1]))
    elif player.x + self.offset_x < self.x-display_scroll[0]:
        self.x -= 1
        if player.y + self.offset_y == self.y - display_scroll[1] and player.x + self.offset_y == self.x - display_scroll[0]:
            display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.animation_images[0], (32, 42)),
                         (self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1]))
        else:
            display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.transform.flip(
                self.animation_images[self.animation_count // 4], True, False),
                (32, 42)), (self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1]))
```

When I run it, and the enemy reaches its location before its time is up, it disappears instead. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Also, `display_scroll` is a list I use to draw all other objects. The player remains in the same spot while everything else moves. `display_scroll[0]` is the x value and `display_scroll[1]` is the y value.

In addition, I added the line `print(self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1])` at the end of the function just to see where python was trying to draw the character. It always printed out normal values, nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: could you gives some more details around variable `display_scroll`

Comment: it might be worth checking the values of `self.x-display_scroll[0]` and `self.y-display_scroll[1]`, if these are negative or greater than the display width/height, then your enemy wouldn't be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is pretty simple:

you are checking

```
if player.x + self.offset_x > self.x - display_scroll[0]:
    [show the image]
elif player.x + self.offset_x < self.x-display_scroll[0]:
    [show the image]
```

so if the enemy is to the right of the player or if it is to the left of the player it will be drawn. but it will not be drawn, if it is on the same x-coordinate as the player.
in order to achieve this you need to add an `else` statement for this:

```
else:
    display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.animation_images[0], (32, 42)),
    (self.x - display_scroll[0], self.y - display_scroll[1]))
    # or whatever animation you want to play
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an else clause and changed some things, and now it works as intended! The enemy also freezes a lot often when its not supposed to, but that's fine as it works with my game.